# Can a process be swapped out from RAM while holding a lock?

Tags: linux-kernel, synchronization, kernel, mutex, spinlock

I am trying to understand the working of **process context switch** and the **process swapping** mechanism specially when a lock is acquired by the process.

Lets assume that a process A has acquired either **Mutex** or **Spinlock**. 
Please correct me if i am wrong below.

In case of **Spinlock**: 
When process has acquired **Spinlock**, The **kernel preemption** is disabled hence there will be no **context switch**, So is it true that disabling preemption(Context Switch) also prevents process from being swapped out?  Or there is other way kernel marks the process "not swap-able" while its holding a **Spinlock** ?

In case of Mutex:
A process can go to sleep state while holding a **mutex**, and also the **preemption is not disabled**. so can this process be swapped out while its holding a **mutex** ? If not then how this process will be prevented from being swapped out ?

Pardon me for my not so clear explanation of the problem.

Platform : Linux on x86

Comment: Why do you think that holding lock in kernel should affect swapping in any way?

Comment: Kernel memory isn't swapped out. User memory may be swapped out, and generally shouldn't be accessed while holding a spinlock unless the pages have been pinned by `get_user_pages` or `get_user_pages_fast`. You can't use `copy_from_user` or `copy_to_user` while holding a spinlock.